# How to calibrate external monitor with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color

I’m trying to calibrate the colour of my external monitor, which attached to my MacBook Pro as a second monitor, with my Spyder 5 colorimeter and DisplayCAL software as the colours are vastly different between the two and assume the MacBook’s is the more accurate one of the two (might calibrate both though but starting with monitor).

My issue is that unlike Windows, where you can delete any current colour profiles and calibrate from the default colours with no profile active, on the Mac it seems like there is always one profile active, and so would make the calibration results inaccurate as a result as they’d be starting at the wrong baseline so to speak.

Is there a way to do this on the Mac to not have any active profile when calibrating?
Or is the default “no active profile” the one at the top which is simply the name of my monitor which the Mac has automatically picked up (in my case "Dell S2716DG)?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter at all what profile you already have loaded or installed.
The current profile is unloaded at the start of calibration… otherwise there would be no good start point.

Mac colour calibration is simply miles ahead of what you can achieve on Windows.